# Fixed width string to sequential structure

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB.NET so I'm not sure if this a dumb question or not..

So I have a large fixed width string I want to parse out into a fixed width structure. I wanted to know if I could just assign it to a sequential structure (Maybe using pointers?) or if using TextFieldParser and individually assigning each field was the only way to go. I have a large string that represents probably 100 different fields but for example purposes of what I'm trying to accomplish I'll provide this.

I'm calling a function that will return a fixed width record like so lets say I have a record like this...

```
Dim inRec as String("FIRST NAME           LAST NAME    03302016")
```

I looked at the MSDN article about creating fixed structure layouts and I don't think I understood it well...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx

From their example could I create a structure like this...

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet := CharSet.Unicode)> _
Structure My_Record
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst := 21)> Public fName As String
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst := 13)> Public lName As String
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst := 8)> Public mDate As String
End Structure

Dim currentRecord as New My_Record
```

Is there a way to assign the inRec string to currentRecord so that the string will line up to fixed width fields in the structure? Or would breaking down inRec using FieldWidths in TextFieldParser then individually assigning them to members of the struct be the only way to go about breaking down a fixed width record like this?

Comment: If you know that the First name will always be 21 chars, the last 13 (?!?) and the date 8, parse it into a class

Comment: I made those lengths up but yes I know all the field lengths will always be fixed and what their widths will be. I saw TextFieldParser would break this down but I thought maybe there was a way to move it to a defined layout rather than executing ReadFields and assigning each field individually.

Comment: CSVHelper will parse them into the class you define and even convert the datatypes where it can.  Its much more powerful/flexible than TextFieldParser

Comment: I'll look into CSVHelper. Thanks for the quick help. Was scratching my head most of the morning.